# What is the correct path for a prefilled Realm file?

Tags: react-native, realm

I have a realm file that is prefilled with the correct data. That file has the following schemas defined:

```
import Realm from 'realm';

let WordSchema = {
  name: 'Word',
  properties: {
    word: 'string',
    definition: 'string'
  }
}

let BookmarkSchema = {
  name: 'Bookmark',
  properties: {
    words: {type: 'list', object: 'Word'}
  }
}

export default new Realm({
  path: 'dictionary.realm',
  schema: [WordSchema, BookmarkSchema]
}
```

I am having huge trouble trying bundle a prefilled Realm database.

Do I have the correct path name? The realm file is located in the same folder as the script.

Thank you for reading my question.